# Pasar una ruta de una carpeta en windows para usar Mounted Files en docker a contenedor con linux

Tags: python, django, docker

Lo que pasa es que tengo una imagen de django al cual quiero usar mounted files para desarrollar mi aplicación y a esta imagen tengo que pasarle mi ruta de la carpeta de aplicación para que compartan esa carpeta, la ruta de mi carpeta de mi aplicacion es `E:\myapp` y la ruta donde se va a guardar mi aplicación en el contenedor es `/usr/src/app`.

Como vera mi SO es windows 10 mientras el contenedor es linux y cuando ejecuto el siguiente comando en la powershell(posicionado en la carpeta de mi app) `docker run -v  ${pwd}:/usr/src/myapp-w /usr/src/jobfind -p 8000:8000 -d -it django bash` me da el siguiente mensaje:

```
{   �   en Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<DoShareAsync>d__8.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Mounting\FileSharing.cs:línea 0
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<ShareAsync>d__6.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Mounting\FileSharing.cs:línea 55
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.<ShareDirectory>d__2.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.HttpApi\Controllers\FilesharingController.cs:línea 21
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
       �8
MoveNext
Docker.ApiServices, Version=2.5.0.49550, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing+<DoShareAsync>d__8
Void MoveNext() �   Docker.ApiServices.}
```

Uso la powershell para usar `${pwd}` así me da la ruta de donde estoy posicionado (en este caso la carpeta de mi app). La verdad no se como pasar le la ruta de mi app desde windows al contenedor linux.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar cuál es el sistema operativo anfitrión de los contenedores docker? ¿Estás usando WSL para tener Linux en Windows o es una máquina virtual o está en otra máquina diferente?

Comment: El SO de mi maquina es Windows 10 Enterprise y uso una maquina virtual para el contenedor linux.

Comment: Si estás usando una máquina virtual, ésta no tiene "visibilidad" del sistema de archivos Windows, por lo que tendrás que proporcionar otro medio para que la máquina virtual tenga visibilidad de los archivos de tu máquina Windows (un punto de montaje CIFS u otro método similar).

Comment: ¿Qué versión exacta de Windows estás usando? Es probable que no necesites crear una máquina virtual para usar Docker y, de paso, que tenga acceso a las unidades Windows haciendo uso de [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop). A través de WSL tendrás más facilidades para conseguir lo que deseas que a través de máquinas virtuales.

Comment: @OscarGarcia tuviste alguna solución? Si es así, puedes compartirla para que los usuarios que tengan el mismo problema puedan resolverlo.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, el problema es que en la configuración de Docker desktop, no tenia agregada la ruta de mis archivos en la opción de Mounted Files, entonces no sabia donde buscar Docker y tiraba ese error, coloque E:\ ahi y ya funciona.

Comment: @DaxTter77 la solución que iba a proponer es que usara Docker Desktop en vez de máquinas virtuales. No entiendo bien su último comentario porque funciona sin tener que configurar ni tocar nada.

Comment: Perdon, me equivoque al principio, leí mal tu respuesta, yo uso Docker desktop, y no tenia agregada la ruta donde estaban mis archivos en Mounted Files

Answer (score 0):

Por las dudas ¿no probaste haciendo?:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 -d -v "E:\myapp:/usr/src/myapp-w" /usr/src/jobfind django bash
```

De esta manera mapeas el Path `E:\myapp` en tu máquina *Windows* para ser utilizada en el docker con el path `/usr/src/myapp-w`.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Esta respuesta deberías haberla planteado como comentario más que como respuesta ya que no es una solución al problema, si no una prueba adicional. Tal y como dije en los comentarios, la máquina donde se creará el docker no tiene visibilidad del sistema de archivos de la máquina Windows, por lo que por mucho que pongas una ruta Windows de manera manual no podrá acceder a esos archivos.